# Implementation of redirection. Unix shell.

Tags: c

```
cat < file.txt < file2.txt
```

I am writing a simple shell and I am thinking of what does mean above expression. It is clear for me what does it mean: cat < file.txt, but double '<' confuses me.

It is a problem to implement redirection because I don't know what can I should expect.

Comment: Which shell? Bash? Have you consulted the man page?

Comment: It's your universe, do whatever you want. This question will attract opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a conventional Unix shell, doing multiple input redirections like that just replaces earlier ones with the last one.  So this:

```
cat < file.txt < file2.txt
```

Just does this:

```
cat < file2.txt
```